# Автоматическое воспроизведение gif

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно сделать так, чтобы gif изображения не воспроизводились в случае, если они находятся не в поле видимости.

Comment: Не показывать их.

Answer (score 1):

При загрузке страницы, удалять гифки, которые не попадают на экран, например, заменять их `src` на несуществующий или делать пустым, при прокрутке, после попадания на экран, заменять `src` изначальным:

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
  
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();  
  var offset;
  var src;
  
  //перебираем все img на странице
  $('img').each(function(){
    
    offset = $(this).offset()['top'];
    
    //Если отступ img от верха больше, чем прокурутка страницы + высота     экрана,
    //то добавляем к scr stopped и класс stopped
    if(offset > (windowHeight + windowScroll)){
      src = $(this).attr('src');
      $(this).attr('src', src.replace('.gif', '_stopped.gif'));
      $(this).addClass('stopped');
    }

  });

 // При прокрутке проверяем, если элемент попал в зону видимости, то удаляем
 // у src часть stopped, тем самым заменяя его на оригинальный и удаляем класс
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    
    $('img').each(function(){
    
      offset = $(this).offset()['top'];
    
      if(offset > (windowHeight + windowScroll)){
        if($(this).hasClass('stopped')){
          $(this).removeClass('stopped')
          src = $(this).attr('src');
          $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_stopped.gif', '.gif'));
        }
      }

    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.image{
  margin-bottom: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
   <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/sxjhMiNxc5mko/200.gif" /> 
 </div>

<div class="image">
   <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/VW1SYCA0YwmAM/200.gif" /> 
 </div>

<div class="image">
   <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/10ebpDhkOpwOmk/200w.gif" /> 
 </div>
```